# Swift: No such module "GoogleMaps" error

Tags: swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to use Google Maps SDK for iOS in Swift. I have been following [these](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start?utm_campaign=mdr-gdl&utm_source=welovemapsdevelopers#adding_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios_to_your_project) steps from google developers website. The problem is when I tried to import GoogleMaps in AppDelegate.swift, it's showing an error like..`No such module 'GoogleMaps'`.

I have added all the frameworks and made necessary changes to Linking and Build settings. Is there anything I'm missing out?

Comment: Have you been able to solve this? Got the same issue rn..

Comment: @user2161301 No I couldn't solve the issue!

Comment: I just deleted this project and I am now recoding everything in Objective C.. who needs swift anyway

Answer (score 4):

The steps on that website are still for Objective-C apps. To write an app in Swift with the Google Maps API, you need to add a [bridging header](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html), and then you can import the module in that header using `#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>`.

In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` instead of using `[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"API_KEY"];` then you use `GMSServices.provideAPIKey("API_KEY")`.

Answer (score 2):

Delete your all of your pod files including workspace except podinstall and lock and install pod again

Comment: Just to clarify, Delete the Pods.xcodeproj, the Google related pods, and the .xcworkspace. Then re-run 'pod install', and this should fix the problem. It is not necessary to delete all pods.

Comment: I guess you are righjt